# chmod 777 Error cannot access operation not permitted

Tags: chmod

While giving `chmod -R 777 dvwa` I get the following error:

```
root@localhost:/var/www/html # chmod -R 777 dvwa
chmod: cannot access 'dvwa/.git/objects/pack/.l2s.tmp_idx_oywRqJ0001': Operation not permitted
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please don't attach pictures of text, and by all means please don't add full-screen screenshots.  Neteller's "Quick and easy online payments" doesn't add anything to your question.

Comment: On what filesystem is `/var/www/html/dvwa` stored?

Comment: What are the output of `df -T /var/www/html/dvwa/.git/objects/pack/.l2s.tmp_idx_oywRqJ0001` and `ls -l /var/www/html/dvwa/.git/objects/pack/.l2s.tmp_idx_oywRqJ0001`?

Comment: It says 'no such file or directory'

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why the error message is `Operation not permitted` but you obviously cannot change the permissions of a non-existing file.

In this case there seems to be a race condition. The file is deleted after the directory content has been read.